# Error on second digits of countdown script

Tags: javascript

I have one script working, but the seconds only apears with one digit.

How can I fix to work with 2 digits?
Example: 4:01 not 4:1

And the countdown must be 5 min

JS :

```
setInterval(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds(); //convet 00:00 to seconds for easier caculation
  var fiveMin = 60 * 15; //five minutes is 300 seconds!
  var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin; // let's say 01:30, then current seconds is 90, 90%300 = 90, then 300-90 = 210. That's the time left
    var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60; //formart seconds into 00:00 
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = result;

}, 500) //calling it every 0.5 second to do a count down
```

HTML :

```
<span id="test">6:00</span>
```

Comment: Does your code actually have those `>`'s in it at the start of every line, or is that just a copy+paste error?

Comment: `("0" + timeleft % 60).substr(-2)`

Answer (score 0):

When you have seconds "x", you can use

```
x = x < 10 ? "0" + x : x
```

to fit standard digital time format

In this case, apply that to `timeleft % 60` near the end of your script. Instead of

```
var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + timeleft % 60;
```

you can have

```
var min = parseInt(timeleft / 60);
var sec = timeleft % 60;
sec = parseInt(sec) < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
var result = min + ":" + sec;
```

Comment: Edited for use context clarity

Comment: A slightly generalizable way to show a whole number padded/truncated to n digits: `(number+100000+"").substr(-n)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [padStart function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```
  var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + (timeleft % 60).toString().padStart(2,'0');
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var seconds = d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds(); //convet 00:00 to seconds for easier caculation
  var fiveMin = 60 * 15; //five minutes is 300 seconds!
  var timeleft = fiveMin - seconds % fiveMin; // let's say 01:30, then current seconds is 90, 90%300 = 90, then 300-90 = 210. That's the time left!
  var result = parseInt(timeleft / 60) + ':' + (timeleft % 60).toString().padStart(2,'0'); //formart seconds into 00:00 
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = result;

}, 500) //calling it every 0.5 second to do a count down
```

```html
<span id="test">6:00</span>
```